# How to Remove weak cipher from esxi ssl server with opnessl command

Tags: ssl, encryption, esxi, weak

I have got SSL cipher issue with my ESXi Server , can anybody provide me the openssl command for the remediation in weak cipher.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this question.  First off, I would have expected that the general mechanism to fix is to patch esxi (the same way I would fix a RHEL box being yum update).  Secondly, if there's a required workaround, I would expect it to involve editing ssl.conf or similar versus running an openssl command, unless the issue is that you need to use openssl to generate a new certificate.  Either way: please provide more details on the issue.

Comment: Actually this issue is with weak cipher for TLS 1.0 and TLS1.1 which are running on my ESXI . is there any way to disable that we cipher which are getting reported by my security server as vulnerability.